# How to individually refer to a dynamically generated bootstrap panels with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to refer to each individual bootstrap panel that has been generated using a 'for' loop in JavaScript but it doesn't work as expected.
Am trying to change it's border color when it is hovered on. Here's the JavaScript code snippet:

```
                     /*****For loop starts here******/
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
                    var title = data.query.search[i].title;
                    var summary = data.query.search[i].page;
                    $('#article').append('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><h4>' + title + '<h4><br><small>' + summary + '</small></div></div>');

                    /*********Here is the hover function********/
                    $(".panel").hover(function() {
                      $(this).css({
                        "border": "2px solid rgb(255,145,0)",
                        "cursor": "pointer"
                      });
                    }, function() {
                      $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ccc");
                    });
                    /********Ends here*************************/

                  }

                  /****For loop ends here*****/
```

The first few panels don't seem to respond to the hover but the others do.
Please what am I doing wrong or rather how do I refer to a dynamically generated bootstrap panels? Thank you.

Here is what am talking about http://codepen.io/ofuochi/full/yOaXgx/
What the code basically does is to fetch Titles from Wikipedia's API based on searched terms. The first three panels don't respond to 'hover' but the rest do. I don't know what exactly am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#searchRow` element is set to `position:absolute` and is above your panels.
You could position `#searchRow` better or set `.panel` to `position:relative` and `z-index` above that of `#searchRow`.

JavaScript is not at fault here although it too could be improved.

If this is all you want from hover I would suggest to do that with css.

Comment: my css was the problem. I set `.panel` to `position:relative` and `z-index:1` just as you suggested and it worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use css

```
#searchRow{
   display: table;
    position: absolute;
/*     height: 100%; *///remove
    width: 100%;
} 

    .panel:hover {
       border: 2px solid rgb(255,145,0);
       cursor: pointer;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJpYqJ

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
$("#article > .panel").on("mouseover", function () {
//stuff to do on mouseover
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the event handler for `hover` *after* the loop, not every time inside the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
    var title = data.query.search[i].title;
    var summary = data.query.search[i].page;
    $('#article').append('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><h4>' + title + '<h4><br><small>' + summary + '</small></div></div>'); 
}

$(".panel").hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "border": "2px solid rgb(255,145,0)",
        "cursor": "pointer"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ccc");
});
```